# Google admob error inflating class com.google.ads.adview with reference from Google Play services library project

Tags: java, android, admob, adview

I have a project that is using google admob. It had `.jar` file in `/libs`, but I want to change it and use google play services. I include it in "Properties>Android>library" from "google-play-services" project. And now i get `error inflating class com.google.ads.adview`.
Can anyone help me why do i get that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the api. You can follow the [official migration guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration)

Basically, you need to make the changes below:

**Change:**

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

**To:**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>


// Java code required.
// testDevices and loadAdOnCreate attributes are
// no longer available.
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
    .build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**Change:**

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"/>
```

**To:**

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" 
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>`
```

**Add:**

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

**Don't forget the permissions:**

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`com.google.ads.adview` is the class from the 6.4.1 (and earlier) versions of Admob.

You want to use `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView`
See https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals